# Logstash issue running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Good day:

I've installed Logstash on ubuntu and trying to run this command from the command line

```
./logstash -f ../config/SalesForceLogStash.conf
```

However, I'm getting the following issues:

```
[INFO ] 2018-07-30 07:47:52.841 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[ERROR] 2018-07-30 07:47:53.180 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) after ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:49:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:167:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:305:in `block in converge_state'"]}
logstash@Logstash:/usr/share/logstash/bin$
```

Thoughts?

**Updated**

This is the content of my SalesForceLogStash.conf [here](https://gist.github.com/dbclkclk/d2b225fa83e74cab5a739b09804b28b0)

I've tested this before which works but, not sure what's happening now.

Comment: Can you also share the content of `SalesForceLogStash.conf` ?

Comment: @Val updated my comment above with a link to the issue. Thanks.

Comment: can you remove all the leading spaces on each line (remove the top level indenting) and make sure that `input` `filter` and `output` start at column 1 ?

Comment: @Val will do..thanks. Will provide an update after I'm done.

Comment: that works..thanks.

Comment: Glad that it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Val indicated, I need to format my `SalesForceLogStash.conf` property with the `input, filter and output` attributes starting at column 1.